# Connecting Lists in Two Sites

Tags: 2013, list, custom-list

I have a list in `Site A` where I enter basic information such as First Name, Last Name, etc.

I need (or would like) for the Site A List information to populate Site B List.

Is this possible in SP 2013?

Comment: Is site B List an exact duplicate list of Site A list?  Or do you want Site B list to refer to the information from Site A list?  Can you give more information what will be saved in Site B List?

Comment: No--Site A is the source of data that I want to flow into Site B.  So when the Name field in Site A is populated, I want it to populate in Site B as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple ways to do that.

If you are running SP2013 on-prem and can deploy managed code, you could use an event receiver on the Site A list to create a new list item on the Site B list.  You (or someone you know) would need to know how to program in C# using the server-side object model in order to do that.

Alternatively, if your farm is set up to use SP2013 workflows, you could create a workflow for the Site A list, and use the new SP2013 workflow action ["Call HTTP web service"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to use SharePoint's own [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) to create the new item in the Site B list.